# Recursion (?) With Advanced Polynomial Form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recursion, sequence-of-function

Let $f_{1}(x)=\sqrt{1-x}$, and for integers $n \geq 2$, let $$f_{n}(x)=f_{n-1}\left(\sqrt{n^2 - x}\right).$$ Let $N$ be the largest value of $n$ for which the domain of $f_n$ is nonempty. For this value of $N,$ the domain of $f_N$ consists of a single point $\{c\}.$ Compute $c.$

When I first saw this I thought there would be a trivial recursion, solvable by listing first few terms, finding a pattern and/or manipulating the equation into a nicer form. I then realized this would be impossible. Nothing is really popping out of me as a possible, nice method to use. Please supply a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you say *I realized this would be impossible*?

Comment: I meant that I realized my technique wouldn't work, not that the problem was impossible.

Comment: @Fleccerd Your technique would work. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_1(x) = \sqrt{1-x}$$

so the domain of $f_1$ is $(-\infty, 1]$. Then
$$f_2(x) = \sqrt{1-\sqrt{4-x}}$$

so the domain of $f_2$ is the set of all the $x$ satisfying $\sqrt{4-x} \leq 1$, i.e. $0 \leq 4-x \leq 1$, i.e. $3 \leq x \leq 4$. Then
$$f_3(x) = \sqrt{1-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{9-x}}}$$

so the domain of $f_3$ is the set of all the $x$ satisfying $3 \leq \sqrt{9-x} \leq 4$, i.e. $9 \leq 9-x \leq 16$, i.e. $-7 \leq x \leq 0$. Then
$$f_4(x) = \sqrt{1-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{9-\sqrt{16-x}}}}$$

so the domain of $f_4$ is the set of all the $x$ satisfying $-7 \leq \sqrt{16-x} \leq 0$, i.e. $\sqrt{16-x} =0$, i.e. $x=16$. Then
$$f_5(x) = \sqrt{1-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{9-\sqrt{16-\sqrt{25-x}}}}}$$
so the domain of $f_5$ is the set of all the $x$ satisfying $\sqrt{25-x}=16$, i.e. $x=-231$. Then
$$f_6(x) = \sqrt{1-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{9-\sqrt{16-\sqrt{25-\sqrt{36-x}}}}}}$$
the domain of $f_6$ is the set of all the $x$ satisfying $\sqrt{36-x}=-231$. So it is empty.

So you have that $N=5$, and $c=-231$.

Comment: Oh, wow! Tremendous!

Comment: This is easy if we always use only the positive values of square root extraction. But why do we throw away the negative ones?

Comment: @DávidLaczkó Because by definition, for $x \geq 0$, $\sqrt{x}$ is the only *non-negative* number whose square is $x$.

Comment: But my question is where does anything say about non-negativity?

Comment: @DávidLaczkó This is the definition of the symbol $\sqrt{}$ : it refers to a non-negative number.

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought the definition was only for the value without the sign. Thanks.